# Cannot populate fields from Ext.data.store

Tags: javascript, extjs, asp-classic

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define('Email', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'emailid',
    fields: [
        { name: 'emailid', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'emailsubject', type: 'string', useNull: true },
        { name: 'emailbody', type: 'string', useNull: true },
        { name: 'emailto', type: 'string', useNull: true },
        { name: 'emailfrom', type: 'string', useNull: true },
    ]
});
```

and DataStore:

```
var EmailDataStore = {

    getDetailStore: function(aid) {    

        var options =  {
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,
            pageSize: 1,
            remoteFilter: true,
            remoteGroup: true,
            remoteSort: true,
            model: 'Email',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'datastores/datastore-email.asp?action=details&auditid=' + aid,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'emailDetails'
                }
            }
        };

        if (typeof (options2) != 'undefined') {
            options = Ext.merge(options, options2);
        }

        var detailStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', options);
        return detailStore;
    }
}
```

I won't include the ASP because the JSON is returning the data appropriately. But in this next bit of code,

```
...
PortalEmailGrid.prototype.detailStore = null;
PortalEmailGrid.prototype.showEmailDetails = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    //alert(id);
    self.detailStore = EmailDataStore.getDetailStore(id);
    //view store at this state - object appears to exist with the returned record in it
    console.log(self.detailStore);

    var firstItem = self.detailStore.first();
    //undefined here
    console.log(firstItem);
    //count is zero, but i can see the object in the console log above
    alert('detailStore count: ' + self.detailStore.count());

    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Email Details',
        store: self.detailStore,
        height: 400,
        width: 800,
        bodyPadding: 4,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'tofield',
                dataIndex: 'emailto',
                fieldLabel: 'To'
            },
                                {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'subjectfield',
                dataIndex: 'emailsubject',
                fieldLabel: 'Subject'
            }

        ]
    });

    win.show();
}
```

I cannot get the fields to populate with the `detailStore`'s data. But when I log `self.detailStore`, in Firebug, I can see the object and its details. `self.detailStore.count()` shows zero, but according to the console, the data should be there. I suspect because of this discrepancy, the fields are not being populated with the `dataIndex` information. Also the previous code block was called by:

```
var selected = self.grid.selModel.selected;
var id = selected.items[0].raw.emailid;
//var status = selected.items[0].raw.status;
PortalEmailGrid.prototype.showEmailDetails(id);
```

**Can you see any reason why the data isn't loading from the datastore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store loading is asynchronous, by the time you're logging the count to the console, the store is yet to be loaded. Firebug always shows the "up to date" status of the object, which is why you can see the data. You need to listen to the load event on the store.

So if you remove the autoLoad config, you can do something like this:

```
self.detailStore = EmailDataStore.getDetailStore(id);
self.detailStore.load({
    callback: function(){
        console.log('loaded, do something');
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay awesome. That makes sense. I'm trying to implement it now. Could you post an example though? I just got thrown into sencha and and am really rusty with my javascript :/
I'll accept you answer when I finish. Thanks.

Comment: Updated OP with an example.

Comment: Okay I got that. But all I want to do after load is populate the fields using the `dataIndex`. I tried putting `win.Show()` inside the callback function, but still no data. Sorry, super newb with this stuff :/

Comment: Not to mention, the template for which is the basis of my entire code doesn't use a load listener, but still works. It is super convoluted though and and in trying to simplify it to the basics I might have lost something...

Comment: I would suggest you read the docs. Window doesn't have a store configuration at all, so not sure where you got that. A store is a collection of records, so it doesn't even make sense to try and bind a store to a form. Have a look at form.Basic::load, it looks more suited to what you want.

Comment: I just meant I opened the window after the load event was called.